# why IIS does not dispatch requests normally between worker processes?

Tags: iis, iis-10, worker-process

I have 10 worker process on an application pool in IIS for one of my websites. Only one of them is on 30% to 40% CPU other are less than 1 percent. My website response time is high and I don't know why IIS is not dispatching requests to the other idle worker processes.

Does anyone know how it actually can be handled?

Comment: 1) It is likely that IIS distributes traffic to an application pool's worker processes in a  round-robin fashion. 2) 10 worker processes for a single pool is a red flag. 3) high response time is another red flag. So in all, you need to consult a very experienced professional to redesign this web app.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.